# Angular2 - 'watch' provider property in multiple components

Tags: angular, observable, eventemitter

I'm coming form NG1 environment and currently I'm creating NG2 app with all available features. Before asking I was exploring google and stackoverflow questions but with no luck since angular 2 moved so fast with api architecture and most answers are out of date.

My case: 
I have Auth provider (service) with property user, I would like to observe user and react in multiple components (navbar, sidebar etc.)

What I tried:

```
@Injectable();
export class Auth {

    private user;
    authorized: EventEmitter<boolean>;

    constructor(public router:Router){
        this.authorized = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
    }

    login(user, token):void{
        localStorage.setItem('jwt', token);
        this.user = _.assign(user);

        this.authorized.emit(<boolean>true);
        this.router.parent.navigateByUrl('/');
    }
}


/***************/
@Component({...})
export class NavComponent {

     public isAuthroized: boolean = false;

     constructor(Auth:Auth){
         Auth.authorized
             .subscribe((data) => this.onUserChanged(data));
     }

     onUserChanged(user){
        alert('USER:' + user.email);
        this.isAuthroized = true;
     }
}

/****************/
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
     ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
     ELEMENT_PROBE_PROVIDERS,
     HTTP_PROVIDERS,
     MapLoader,
     Auth
])
```

But with no luck. Should I use Observable EventEmitter or maybe there is other correct approach to handle this case? In NG1 it would be as simple as set $watch on service's property. Thanks!

EDIT:
I added new method to Auth service:

```
...
userUpdated: EventEmitter<boolean>;

constructor(public router:Router){
    this.userUpdated = new EventEmitter<any>();
}

...

logout(returnUrl?: string): void{
    delete this.user;
    localStorage.removeItem('jwt');
    this.userUpdated.emit(undefined);

    if(!_.isEmpty(returnUrl)){
        this.router.parent.navigateByUrl(returnUrl);
    }

}
```

And now event is called, why is this working for logout and not for login?

EDIT 2:

```
export class LoginPageComponent {
   error: string;

   constructor(public http: Http, public router: Router, public Auth:Auth){
   }

   login(event, email, password){
      ...
      this.http.post('/api/login', loginModel, {headers: headers})
        .map((res) => res.json())
        .subscribe((res: any) => {
            this.Auth.login(res.user, res.ADM_TOKEN);
        }, (error) => this.error = error._body);
   }

}
```

RESOLVED

Silly mistake.. i left in NavComponent in providers array [Auth].. so it was different object than global Auth.. sorry guys! Hope this issue will help somebody new in Angular2. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: So your `onUserChanged` doesn't get called after `Auth.login()` is called? I rebuilt a simple version of your example (in Dart and without routing and localstorage) and it's working fine.

Comment: Exactly! I was analyzing @thierry templier response and I have same code as he and still no alert in onUserChanged. When I'm debugging NavComponent subscribe is fired only on constructor init.

Comment: Not sure I understand your last comment. Could it be that your `NavComponent` is created only after the event was fired?

Comment: I think we need to see a running example where this can be reproduced.

Comment: What do you mean by "subscribe is fired only on constructor init"? Do you receive the `userUpdated` event for login?

Comment: Yes, great idea, Günter, because events are fired on my side!

Comment: Just a question. How the `login` method is called?

Comment: I mean:
    constructor(public Auth:Auth){
        Auth.userUpdated.subscribe(alert('called'));
    }
but probably with first init subscibe value (null)?

Comment: I added 2nd update with calling login function

Comment: Just a silly question: are you sure that the `login` method is called? I mean that your `/api/login` request is successful...

Comment: Yes, what's more token is present in localStorage and with logout it's removed. I have no idea what's going on.. even if I remove redirection still no luck..

Comment: When I was deeply debugging event emit I noticed that when calling login function i have empty array of observers attached to it on the other hand logout function shows 1 observer.

Comment: So it was my first guess even though only because I didn't read your code to the end :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are adding `Auth` as provider to every component. This creates a new instance of the class for each component.
Add it only in `bootstrap(AppComponent, providers: [...])` or only on the `AppComponent`.

Answer (score 1):

You can notice that there is no watch feature in Angular since it's now managed by Zones.

To notify other components, you could add another `EventEmitter` within your `Auth` service for the `userUpdated` event. The components that want to be notified could register on this emitter.

```
@Injectable();
export class Auth {
  private user;
  authorized: EventEmitter<boolean>;
  userUpdated: EventEmitter<boolean>;

  constructor(public router:Router){
    this.authorized = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
    this.userUpdated = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  }

  login(user, token):void{
    localStorage.setItem('jwt', token);
    this.user = _.assign(user);

    this.authorized.emit(<boolean>true);
    this.userUpdated.emit(this.user);
    this.router.parent.navigateByUrl('/');
  }
}
```

Components could register on this event:

```
@Component({...})
export class NavComponent {
  (...)
  constructor(Auth:Auth){
    Auth.userUpdated
         .subscribe((data) => this.onUserChanged(data));
  }
}
```

You could also provide the user when emitting the `authorized` event:

```
  login(user, token):void{
    localStorage.setItem('jwt', token);
    this.user = _.assign(user);

    this.authorized.emit(this.user);
    this.router.parent.navigateByUrl('/');
  }
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Ok, but this is property of service not of component. How component may know that service's field has changed?

Comment: In fact, there is no `$watch` support in Angular2 since there is no more  concept of scope. Other components would need to subscribe on an `userChanged` event. I updated my answer in that way.

Comment: You could also provide the user when sending the `authorized` event instead of `true`....