# how to save and retrieve data from Angular2 local storage?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, angular-local-storage

I was able store an auth token in the browser's `localstorage`, but I wasn't able retrieve it as string. I can't find any examples on how to do that.

Comment: Could you paste your code that retrieves the local storage please?

Comment: There's another question addressing this that recommends using a service and Observables, to be able to keep track of changes to localStorage items: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397198/how-can-i-watch-for-changes-to-localstorage-in-angular2

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could write yourself a service to encapsulate the serializing and deserializing:

```js
export class StorageService {
    write(key: string, value: any) {
        if (value) {
            value = JSON.stringify(value);
        }
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    }

    read<T>(key: string): T {
        let value: string = localStorage.getItem(key);

        if (value && value != "undefined" && value != "null") {
            return <T>JSON.parse(value);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Add it to your providers either in the `bootstrap` call:

```js
bootstrap(App, [ ..., StorageService]);
```

or in your root component:

```js
@Component({
    // ...
    providers: [ ..., StorageService]
})
export class App {
    // ...
}
```

Then in the component where you need it, just inject it in the constructor:

```js
export class SomeComponent {
    private someToken: string;

    constructor(private storageService: StorageService) {
        someToken = this.storageService.read<string>('my-token');
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: `read<T>(key: string): T {` should be `read<T>(key: T): T {` ...correct?

Comment: No, `T` is the type of the value. The key is a string - the name of the stored value. :)

Comment: It is giving null