# Is it possible to use a singleton service and share data between two components opened in different tab in angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular

My question is as it says in the title:

*Is it possible to use a singleton service and share data between two components opened in different tab in angular 5?*

I'm using a singleton service, where the provider for the service is injected at *app module* layer.

However, when I open a component in another tab, the data set in the service is no longer available in the opened component?

Is there anyway I could share data between components opened in different tab in angular 2?

I know this can be achieved via `local storage` and it's `storage` event in html5/javascript, I'm looking for something specific in angular 5?

I did go thru the "duplicate" question as marked, and I did mention about `local storage and storage event`, however, I wanted if there is any "angular" way of doing things.

Thank you.

Comment: 2 tabs means 2 separate windows and 2 app instances regardless of framework used. Could use postMessage API also to communicate between windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communication between tabs or windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows)

Comment: Reference this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382775/angular-2-single-service-provider-across-multiple-browser-windows/45382965#45382965

I thought it wasn't possible with Angular but then this poster found the solution.

Comment: @joshrathke, I read it, but it does not say anything about "communicating between two tabs"? can you please elaborate?

Comment: Using a browser tool like LocalStorage or cookies sounds like your best bet here, depending on how secure you need to keep the data between tabs.

Comment: I agree. The gist of all of the solutions you will find is that Angular can't do this directly, but can do it through tools that access local storage.