# Angular 2+ Interaction between separate windows/tabs

Tags: angular, typescript

I've searched about this topic but couldn't find anything relevant.
I would like to know if, using Angular 2+ (optimally v5.4.2), something like this is possible.

Let me define a quick use case :

> - I have an app with multiple routes,
> - open a browser on app/route1 (window1),
> - open a second browser window on app/route2 (window2)
> - have a user input on window2
> - change data/ui on window1 according to the previous input.

Again, I don't even know if that is possible so even a simple "You can't" is ok with me.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: It is possible if you save the input to your db and have some `timer` running in background which fetches data from the the `db` at regular intervals

Comment: You could go for a realtime database like firebase. This will of course mean you have to post the data to the server, but the data will be updated in the second window realtime (e.g. no refresh needed)

Comment: I don't know if you can use sockets (see an example to make a chat in https://medium.com/dailyjs/real-time-apps-with-typescript-integrating-web-sockets-node-angular-e2b57cbd1ec1 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is several ways to achieve this.

If window2 input is updating data on a remote server, you could use websockets or any other real time technology to notify window1 that your data has changed.

An other alternative would be to use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). You should check out this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382775/angular-2-single-service-provider-across-multiple-browser-windows) for more informations on that.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll try with localstorage to see if it fits my needs.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's not tested, I am not sure if it's working but have you tried using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to do this? Otherwise, since a new window is always a new instance of the app, I don't think that anything directly in Angular would work (not sure though).

Otherwise, if you have a expressjs (or Node.js) server setup, you can store your data this way.

Comment: correct, `localStorage` will work if both the windows are from the same browser..

Comment: Localstorage seems like a good way to do what I want. I'll try that, thanks