# angular 4- logout automatically in all tabs when logged out in one open tab

Tags: angular, local-storage, logout

I wanted to logout automatically from all the open tabs when logged out in one open tab.

I'm setting a jwt token to localStorage on login and removing the token when logout.

How do I use storage events to logout from all open tabs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I watch for changes to localStorage in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397198/how-can-i-watch-for-changes-to-localstorage-in-angular2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add event listener on storage as:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', (event) => {
  if (event.storageArea == localStorage) {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('jwt_token');
    if(token == undefined) { // you can update this as per your key
        // DO LOGOUT FROM THIS TAB AS WELL
        this.router.navigate(['/']); // If you are using router
        // OR
        window.location.href = '<home page URL>';
    }
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: I can see the alert in other tab, How do I logout user? `(event) => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('jwt_token') == null) {
    alert('yes');
  }
 }`

Comment: @RNKushwaha you can write above code in app.component within `ngOnInit` method.