# window.onstorage is not working with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, window-object

I'm trying to create window event listener that must listen for the event in the other tab, where opened another instance of the same application.
**Some service:**

```
public validateItemAgainstServer = (item: EspApplication) => {
    ...
         window.localStorage.setItem('item', "|")
      ...
    });
  }
```

**Component**

```
constructor(private winRef: WindowRef) {
    winRef.nativeWindow.addEventListener('storage', function (e) {
      console.log("storage event occured");
   }, false);
    window.addEventListener('storage', function (e) {
      console.log("storage event occured");
   }, false);
  }
```

**WinRef**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

function _window(): any {
   // return the global native browser window object
   return window;
}

@Injectable()
export class WindowRef {
   get nativeWindow(): any {
      return _window();
   }
}
```

Regretfully, onstorage event was not fired. Is it possible to fix this solution or may be there is some better ideas of how to synchronize two tabs in Angular?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I watch for changes to localStorage in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47683091/11065438)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I watch for changes to localStorage in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397198/how-can-i-watch-for-changes-to-localstorage-in-angular2)

Comment: Could you check (via Browser) if window.localStorage.getItem('item') has any value?

Comment: @JoshGuzman, what is interesting, event was fired if manually remove value from localStorage via dev tools and yes - there was not value on getItem()

Comment: Well, after applying bind to event listener function it starts to work.

Comment: I would recommend you this article for a better understanding about the subject
https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3191-syncing-localstorage-in-memory-cache-with-storage-events-in-angular-2-1-1.htm

Comment: You could use arrow functions instead of `bind()`, or even `fromEvent('storage')` from RxJS as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Check the live example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h7iuws)!

```
  @HostListener('window:storage')
  onStorageChange() {
    console.log('change...');
  }
```